# RxJS DOM pause observable while another "is dragging"?

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, rxjs-dom

**UPDATE**

I've tried to make a standalone version here: https://codepen.io/neezer/pen/pPRJar

It doesn't work quite like my local copy, but I'm hoping it similar enough that you can see where I'm trying to go.

I'm not getting quite the same behavior as well because I changed the listener target to `document`, which seemed to help some.

Also, I'm using RxJS v5 and the latest version of React.

---

Still getting the hang of [RxJS](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS)...

I have two Observables: one subscribed to mouseover x coordinates on a table to show a resize column, and the other to allow the user to drag on that column.

Roughly speaking, the first one looks like this (all of the below defined in a `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method in a React component):

```
Rx.DOM.mouseover(tableEl)
  .map(/* some complicated x coordinate checking */)
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .subscribe(/* setState call */)
```

That works great, and gives me this:

[image: img]

So now I want to provide the actual "drag" behavior, and I tried setting up a new Observable like so

```
// `resizerEl` is the black element that appears on hover
// from the previous observable; it's just a div that gets
// repositioned and conditionally created
Rx.DOM.mousedown(resizerEl)
  .flatMap(md => {
    md.preventDefault()

    return Rx.DOM.mousemove(tableEl)
      .map(mm => mm.x - md.x)
      .takeUntil(Rx.DOM.mouseup(document))
  })
  .subscribe(/* do column resizing stuff */)
```

There are three problems with that:

1. Once I've done my first "drag", I can't do any more. My understanding is that `takeUntil` completes the Observable, and I'm not sure how I can "restart" it.
2. The `mousemove` from the first observable is still active while I'm dragging, so my black div will disappear once my `x` position changes enough to trigger that behavior.
3. The binding on the second Observable doesn't always seem to trigger (it's unreliable). I think there might be a race condition or something happening here because sometimes I'll refresh the page and I'll get the drag *once* (from #1), and other times I won't get it at all.

[image: ss]

Note at first after a clean refresh I can't drag the handle (#3), then I refresh, and I can't drag the handle past the bounds setup from the first Observable--and the black resizer bar disappears and reappears as my mouse's x coordinate enters and leaves that envelope (#2).

---

I've been head-banging on this for quite some time now and would really appreciate any insight as to what I'm doing wrong here. In short, I want

- the first Observable to "pause" when I'm dragging, then resume when I'm done dragging
- the second Observable to not "complete" (or "restart") once a drag is done
- the second Observable to reliably work

As I mentioned earlier, I currently have this logic setup in a React component's `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method, the shape of which looks roughly like this:

```
componentWillUpdate() {
  // bail if we don't have the ref to our table
  if (!tableEl) {
    return;
  }

  // try not to have a new Observable defined on each component update
  if (!this.resizerDrag$ && this.resizer) {
    this.resizerDrag$ = // second Observable from above
  }

  // try not to have a new Observable defined on each component update
  if (!this.resizerPos$) {
    this.resizerPos$ = // first Observable from above
  }
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to get a jsfiddle or jsbin that minimally replicates the issue. I have some ideas of what could be but it is hard to say without doing some debugging. Suffice to say I don't see anything *obviously* wrong with your code, but there are some pieces missing.

Comment: @paulpdaniels Updated my question with an example, though it's not a 1-to-1 of my original code. I tried my best to replicate it without all the dynamic calculations happening in my actual app.

Answer (score 0):

I've played around with this a bit now, I don't think this answer will be complete, but I'd like to share my insights. Hopefully a more advanced RxJS mind will chime in, and we can all work together to figure it out :).

I recreated a "lite-er" version of this in CodePen, using some light jQuery manipulation as opposed to React. Here's what I have so far:

#### "the first Observable to "pause" when I'm dragging, then resume when I'm done dragging"

Solving the first point helps with the other two. Based on what I had to do to get my `resizerEl`, I get the feeling it is rendered in the `render` method of the component based on something in `this.state`. If this is true, that means that when the first observable still has the ability to create and destroy `resizerEl` even while the second observable is listening. This means that `resizerEl` will no longer be able to generate any events, even though the observable doesn't complete until you've moused up.

In my case, I noticed that if you moved the mouse fast enough to go outside of width of what you were trying to drag, it would eliminate `resizerEl`, which is of what we want, but not while we're trying to drag something!

**My solution:** I introduced another variable to the "state" of the "component". This would set to `true` when we moused down on `resizerEl`, and then `false` when we moused up again.

Then we use `switchMap`.

```
  Rx.DOM.mousemove(tableEl)
  .switchMap(function(event) {
    return this.state.mouseIsDown ? Rx.Observable.never() : Rx.Observable.of(event);
  })
  .map(...
```

There's probably a better way to do it rather than just sticking `event` back in an Observable, but this was the last part of it I worked on and my brain is kind of fried hehe. The key here is switching to `Observable.never` while the mouse is down, that way we don't go any further down the operator chain.

***Actually,*** one nice thing is that this may not even need to be put in `this.state`, since that would cause a re-render. You can probably just use an instance variable, since the variable is only essential to the Observables functionality, and not any rendering. So, using `this.mouseIsDown` would be just as good.

How do we handle the mouse being down or up?

Part 1:

```
...
Rx.DOM.mousedown(resizerEl)
  .do(() => this.mouseIsDown = true)
```

Better to abstract this to a function of course, but this is the gist of what it does.

Part 2:

```
...
return Rx.DOM.mousemove(tableEl)
  .map(mm => mm.x - md.x)
  .takeUntil(Rx.DOM.mouseup(document))
  .doOnCompleted(() => this.mouseIsDown = false)
```

Here we take advantage of `doOnComplete` to perform this side-effect once the observable has completed, which in this case, would be on `mouseup`.

#### "the second Observable to not "complete" (or "restart") once a drag is done"

Now here's the tricky one, I never ran into this problem. You see, every time `Rx.DOM.mousedown(resizerEl)` emits an event, inside of `flatMap`, a *new Observable is created each time* with `return Rx.DOM.mousemove(tableEl)...`. I used RxJS 4.1 when making this, so it's possible that there could be behavioral differences, but I found that just because the inner observable completed didn't mean the outer one would complete as well.

So what *could* be happening? Well, I'm thinking that since you're using React, that `resizerEl` is being created/destroyed respectively when the component is rendering. I haven't seen the rest of your code of course, but **please correct me** if I'm wrong about this assumption.

This wasn't a problem for me because, for the sake of simplicity, I simply re-used the same element as a dragger, only hiding it when I wasn't hovering over a draggable element.

So the important question is: how is `resizerEl` being defined and used in your component? I'm assuming the actual reference to it is made using, well, a `ref`. But if it that DOM element is ever destroyed or recreated, then the `Rx.Dom` binding needs to be repeated all over again.

I see you're doing this with `componentDidUpdate`. However, the `Rx.Dom.mousedown` event may still be bound to an old copy of the ref to `resizerEl`. Even if the component destroys the resizer in the DOM, and sets the `ref` (I assume that is `this.resizer`) to `null` or `undefined`, that does not destroy the Observable that is bound to that element. In fact, I don't even think it removes it from memory, even if it's removed from the DOM! That means that `this.resizerDrag$` will never evaluate to `false`/`null`, and it will still be listening to an element that is no longer in the DOM.

If that is the case, something like this in `componentWillUpdate` might help:

```
if (!this.resizerDrag$ && this.resizer) {
    this.resizerDrag$ = // second Observable from above
  }
  else if (!this.resizer && this.resizerDrag$) {
    this.resizerDrag$ = null;
  }
```

This will remove the Observable if the resizer object ceases to exist, that way we can properly reinitialise it upon it's return. There's a better to way to do with `Subjects`, keeping the subscription to one subject and just subscribing the subject to different mousedown streams once they become available, but let's keep this simple :).

This is something where we'd have to see the rest of your code (for this component) tell what's going on, and figure how to address it. But, my hypothesis is that you'd need to intentionally destroy the Observable if `this.resizer` is ever removed.

#### the second Observable to reliably work

Pretty sure that once the above two issues work, this one goes away. Nice and easy!

#### The CodePen

Here is the very naive mockup I made of this problem:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KmapYZ

Drag the blue circles back and forth along the X axis. (Has some little problems and bugs unrelated to the scope of this question, so I'm not worried about them.)

I made some slight changes of course just to keep it in-step with the more dumb downed approach I used. But all the concepts are there, as well as most of the code you wrote, modified to match this approach.

As I mentioned before, I didn't encounter the problem of the dragging only working once, so this better demonstrates the solution to pausing the first Observable. I re-use the dragging element, which I assume is why I didn't run into the 'drag-only-once' problem.

I hope that you or anyone else can comment with some improvements to this approach, or just show us a better (potentially more idiomatic) approach.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed answer, @Amleonard! I'll update my question with some details its now clear to me I forgot, but I'd love to hear more about "There's a better to way to do with Subjects, keeping the subscription to one subject and just subscribing the subject to different mousedown streams once they become available"... as I'm exploring something similar with BehaviorSubject

Comment: Updated my question with a CodePen that sorta-kinda mimics my behavior (whole bunch of hard-codes where I'd normally have dynamic values).

Comment: I'll also note that I was copying the drag example from the RxJS docs: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/events.md

Comment: @neezer I'm just having trouble with the example because the hover positions aren't matching the line positions hehe. The first one does, until it's dragged, the second one doesn't though.